# differences between int32.Equals int? == int? for linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, equality

I know the title is not very clear but here is the problem. I am trying to develop simple web page with asp.net mvc and I have category controller and try to explain situation at the below code block.

```
    //
    // GET: /Category/
    public ViewResult Index(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            //Gives the following error if nut null, 1,2 etc
            //Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. 
            //LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.
            var categories = db.Categories.Where( c => Int32.Equals(c.ParentCategoryId, id));
            return View(categories);
        }
        else
        {
            //Does not show any category, must show item if ParentCategoryId is null
            var categories = db.Categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == id);
            return View(categories);
        }
    }
```

My data is

```
ID    Name            ParentId
----------------------------------
1   Computer    NULL
2   TV          NULL
3   Laptop          1
4   Desktop         1
```

Comment: basicly, `Int32.Equals` convert handle them as a object and it sql equivalent is "IS" in my case it result `[Exten1].[ParentCategoryId] IS NULL` (!c.ParentCategoryId.HasValue has the same result).

and `==` SQL result is "=". This does not explain the error message of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public ViewResult Index(int? id = 0)
    {
        var categories = db.Categories
            .Where(c => (c.ParentId.HasValue ? c.ParentId : 0) == id)
                 .ToList();
        return View(categories);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Linq to anything the answer depends on the Linq provider implementation and how/if they chose to handle this case.

When you write `c => c.ParentCategoryId == id`, this is an expression tree. The Linq provider breaks this down into (1) a property access (`ParentCategoryId`), (2) a variable access (`id`), and (3) it ties the two operands together with an equality comparison (`==`). This code doesn't actually run as a function, it's just processed as an expression

Likewise, `c => Int32.Equals(c.ParentCategoryId, id)` is broken down into a method call (`Int32.Equals`) which takes two parameters. The Linq provider chose to implement a call to `Int32.Equals` as the same as `==` then this should be identical. However, it's more likely that they didn't

The second Linq statement is probably getting converted to

```
select * from Categories where ParentCategoryId = NULL
```

Which is never true in ANSI SQL, so you get 0 records every time. You'll have better luck saying `.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId != null)` or `.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId.HasValue)`. Again, this depends on what the creators of the Linq provider chose, but one of those is bound to work the way you expect.

Comment: yes, this is right. I think the `Int32.Equals` should use `IS` when the value is `null` otherwise `=` for creating the SQL. Well, currently this is the only way to the this type of staff, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    if (id == null)
    {
      var categories = db.Categories.Where( c => !c.ParentCategoryId.HasValue); 
      ..             
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response but it is not the question `Int32.Equals` does the same job. what I am asking is why I cannot use only one linq for this case.